Emacs: How to use CUA mode cut and copy with multiple-cursors
I have CUA mode enabled (cua-mode +1) and multiple-cursors.el installed.
In the following snippet,
{
  "a": 123,
  "b": 123,
  "c": 123,
}

I'd like to be able to mark the first "1", then do
C-d  ; my hotkey for mc/mark-next-like-this
C-d  ; all the 1s are marked and multiple cursors is still active
C-x  ; cut the 1s out

Neither cut, nor copy with the CUA keybindings seem to work while multiple cursors is active.
C-c gives C-c is undefined
C-x seems to do nothing and kind get gets me stuck until I C-g out a few times, unless I only have 2 selections, in which case it has the effect of exchange-mark-and-point.
I also tried adding this to my doom config and it had no effect.
(map! :after multiple-cursors-core
      :map mc/keymap
      "C-c" #'cua-copy-region
      "C-x" #'cua-cut-region)

